# knockout binding to C# double initial value blank

Tags: knockout.js, bind

I have some html input elements bound to an object which has properties of C# type "double". Is there a way I can bind the value of my input to these properties but display nothing if the actual property is zero rather than "0"?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [writeable computed](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html#writeable_computed_observables) in your view model to ensure that you return an empty string instead of 0.

Alternatively you could use a custom binding to avoid messing with it on the view model side.  A sample might look like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.valueNoZero = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, all, data, context) {
        //create a writeable computed on-the-fly to handle not showing zero values
        var formatter = ko.computed({
            read: function() {
                var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());

                //if value is zero return empty
                return value || "";
            },
            write: function(newValue) {
                var value = valueAccessor();

                //write numeric value
                value(!newValue || isNaN(newValue) ? 0 : parseInt(newValue, 10));
            },
            disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved: element
        });

        ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { value: formatter }, context);       
    }
};
```

The idea is that it creates a writeable computed in the binding to place in-between the actual value and your input.

Sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/Zt25k/